# is it possible to directly execute this within the view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

i need to get a seperate data from a different query, question is, if such code is possible to execute?or is there any other workaround or way to make one of these thanks!

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
    </td>
    <td>
        @{
            sqls = "select sum(Disc-Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price))as D 
                        from table "
            DB.Open();
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = DB.getData(sqls);
            int P =ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["D"];
            return P;
        }
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
    </td>
</tr>
}
```

Comment: it is possible to write any c# code inside view

Comment: best method is having a view model, that will have all the data necessary to fill the view, pass only that model to view.... (there is some uses to this method - you can update a live site without resetting it, which in case of class or controllers will reset the session and restart the site)

Answer (score 0):

It is best to seperate login concerns from view and place it in controller. View works like a template for displaying data processed by controller and therefore should remain consistent throughout the project.From your code it seems like you need to retrieve 2 database tables data, in that case use ViewModel to join the 2 classes( I assume you have the 2 classes in Model) and controller will process what you need to get and return ViewModel to your view.Remember though you need to strongly bind the ViewModel to your view.

Comment: yes, 2 queries on different database. i guess im gonna have to study that viewModel.

Comment: Good, you will find it very easy to display whatever data you wish on View with ViewModel. Good Luck! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Any code CAN be executed from the view, but one needs to ask whether it should be.

I suggest reading up more on the MVC design pattern and what it is supposed to achieve. In short the view is only a visual representation of data and business logic that has been processed in other application layers, and this is then supplied by the model.

So rather do that data access elsewhere and place the result on the model.

Comment: thanks, thats why im asking if there are any other workaround or code for it

Comment: It's really not a matter of a 'workaround', it's a matter of using the MVC architecture as it should be used. What you've done above is a 'workaround' since you're bypassing the intended structure.

Comment: in my case i dont see any other way to load that particular column, that will came from another model or database perhaps.

Comment: another way i see here is to manually fill a List that will contain my data i needed it to be

Comment: But your view has access to the model, and is using that as a basis for the data query. Your model was in turn populated by some other type. So why can't that type do the same logic as you're trying to do in your view? It's just iterating the model.

Answer (score 0):

You can execute c# code in view too (your code is wrong anyways as it says `return P` which does nothing here), **But the purpose of MVC is not to do this type of mix in the code**.

The reason MVC was a hit is because of separation of concern. We have more flexibility if we follow this rule, **Use the Views only to display data** and not do any logical stuff there, **Controllers are the place where you must write your logic's**

We can change your code to follow MVC pattern as below.

Just before you `return View(model)` from your controller do the same `foreach` loop and get the required data and assign it to a new property.

```
    foreach (var item in ModelList)    // ModelList must be your List of model variable
    {
     sqls = "select sum(Disc)as D from table
             where P = Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)";
     DB.Open();
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds = DB.getData(sqls);
     int P =ds.Tables[0].Rows[0]["D"];
     item.P = P;                     //assigning to a new property P
    }

   return View(ModelList);
```

Now you have the required values in a property of each item. You can simply display them in the view as below.

```
     @foreach (var item in Model) {
            <tr>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ReleaseDate)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Genre)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @item.P
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id=item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id=item.ID }) |
                    @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.ID })
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
```

Comment: will try this thanks! at least it still preserves the MVC

Comment: hello, your answer will produce same columns value for @item.P, wherein every rows there are different disc value. so for me it really needs to execute another query for every rows in that particular column only

Comment: @JJBG in the controller side we are executing different queries for each item right? So it must have different values. Can you recheck if anything is wrong in controller side

Comment: yes different queries, because it will came from different database too, nothing is wrong on both controllers, its just that it produces same out put for item.P.

Comment: @JJBG then you must use somekind of `switch` case and execute different queries, I just gave you a MVC convention coding out of your original code.